# Configure Android hash for Facebook on Windows for Titanium/ Alloy/ Appcelerator

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I am trying to to add Facebook login on Android as described here: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook

I followed the instructions, however when I attempt to login, it say "No Android key hashes are configured".

On the following link: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook it says to use the following command to create the hash:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.3.GA/dev_keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

However, I am using windows, and the above seems suited to OSX.

I believe only the following portions needs to be adjusted:

```
-keystore ~/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.3.GA/dev_keystore
```

But it's not clear what they should be changed to.

Therefore my question is how do I configure my Android Hash for Facebook on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and experimentation I found that the command is actually as follows:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias tidev -keystore C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\<version>\android\dev_keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

with password `tirocks`

Note that it should be `tidev` instead of `androiddebugkey`.

It should also be `C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\<version>\android\dev_keystore` instead of `~/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.3.GA/dev_keystore`.